# I am able to create a class object even when it is giving compilation error in Java

Tags: java, java-7

Today, I came across a scenario where I have not overridden all the methods of the interface in the child class. However, when I tried to create an object of the child class, it still worked fine. My assumption so far is that we cannot create the objects unless all the compilation errors are resolved.

Please shed some light on this.

Example I have taken.

```
interface Parent {
   public void test();
}

class Child implements Parent {
   public void print() {
      System.out.println("Didn't expect to print");
   }
}
```

The Child class was giving me the compile time error asking me to override the methods from the interface. Ignoring the error, when I tried to create the object like below and execute the next statement, it gave me the output as indicated at the bottom.

```
Child child = new Child();
child.print();
```

Output:

```
Didn't expect to print
```

P.S: I tried this on Java 7

Please let me know if my basic understanding (that Java objects cannot be created without resolving compilation errors) is wrong

Comment: how you ignored the error?

Comment: @Pooya, please see my comment on Adam's answer

Comment: It makes no sense. Try run `child.test()`

Comment: @Héctor, in that case, it gives me error - `Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type Test1 must implement the inherited abstract method Test.test()`. But my question why didn't it throw the error when invoking the `print` method

Answer (score 6):

This is only possible if your IDE cached the `Child` class before you added the `Parent` to it as a superclass. Otherwise this won't compile at all.

Comment: Actually this happened in a real word scenario. Not just on IDE. Initially the child class was implementing the interface and both were packed together (although they are separate jars) and released to the client environment. Then we have modified the interface which now includes a new method and released just that jar (the jar which contains the child class is still not modified). And the child class seems to have working fine without issues - @Adam Arold

Comment: @Ravi That's just a different path to the same result. You have an old working `Child.class` file on your system that doesn't know about the changes to the Parent. That Child class wasn't compiled with the new Parent class, so the compiler won't protect you.

Comment: @Adam Arold, as an experiment, I just did the following.
1. Create interface `Parent`
2. Create class `Child` and inherit `Parent`.
3. Try to run it.
4. There was no error in printing. It still printed the output

Comment: You also need to recompile `Child` to pick up the changes. If you have multiple jars, the old `Child` is still using the old `Parent`. Try `clean`-ing your project.

Answer (score 2):

I just did the following to reproduce this condition (from the command line, so there are no IDE shenanigans going on):

1. Create the Parent interface without the `test` method declaration.
2. Create the Child class that implements Parent.
3. Create a Driver class with a `main` method that instantiates a Child object and calls `print`.
4. Compile everything with no errors.

Everything works, as expected.

I then added the `test` method declaration to the Parent interface and tried to compile the Child class and got the expected error message:

> Child is not abstract and does not override abstract method test() in Parent

I get the same error if I try to compile the Driver class.

But when I check my file system, the old Child.class file is still there, and the Driver program that uses it still runs fine. These are outdated copies of the class files that weren't replaced or deleted when I tried to compile again. A typical build would clean those up before compiling, ensuring that outdated classes aren't part of a new distribution.

Comment: Thanks for trying out @Bill. That is definitely not the case with me as we remove the old jars and replace them with the new ones. Can I ask you for a favor? Can you repeat the same steps as described in your answer? However, please declare `test` method in the interface and now define the `Child` class but do not override the `test` method. Can you now create the `Child` class object in the `Driver` class and invoke `print` method on it and run it?

Comment: @Ravi My Child class already does not override the `test` method. I didn't change Child.java after its original creation, only Parent.java.

Comment: Exactly @Bill, the behavior is unexpected even if you leave the Parent.java as it is without changing anything. There is no old .class file in my case

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you have two classes with the same name and package in the classpath, Java looks for the first one it finds and use it. So if there is already another version of your Parent.class there without the added function it may be chosen over the new one.

Comment: That was not the case. The old jar was removed and the new jar was placed - @Pooya